# how to alphabetically order strings in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, alphabetical

i have the following md-collection that loads a list of emails as follows

```
<md-collection-item repeat.for="u of user" class="accent-text">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>${findEmailAddress(u.email)}</p>
                                </div>          
                            </div>
                        </md-collection-item>
```

and in typescript

```
findEmailAddress(userId: string) {
         return ((this.Persons|| []).find(x => x.userId == userId) || {}).email;
    
    }
```

it gets the emails for that user and displays it like

```
peaches@test.com
apple@test.com
pineapple@test.com
banana@test.com
```

how can i get it to load the emails in alphabetical order like

```
apple@test.com
banana@test.com
peaches@test.com
pineapple@test.com
```

i tried using sort like

```
let test =((this.Persons|| []).find(x => x.userId == userId) || {}).email;
 return test.sort() ---> but it fails on sort and says "sort does not exists on type string"
```

Comment: Your `findEmailAddress(userId)` function returns the email of a single user, not the list of emails of all users, therefore there is nothing to sort.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#find` function returns the first element which satisfies condition.

So in your code

```js
let test =((this.Persons|| []).find(x => x.userId == userId) || {}).email;
```

`test` will be a `string`, not `array` type, and so that's the reason you're getting the current error.

To show sorted email addresses, you should sort the data source `user`.

I assume that `user` is array type. So in this case you can sort it by `email`.

```
const sorted = user.sort((a, b) => a.email - b.email)
```

```
<md-collection-item repeat.for="u of sorted" class="accent-text">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example test returns a string instead of an array. Sort must be called on an array of strings.

You must first get this string to be an Array. Assuming that test contains a list of linebreak separated email addresses, you could try to split with a linebreak and then sort like this:

```
test.split("\n").sort();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split